# Monit configuration reload - supposed to restart monitored services?

Tags: ubuntu, service, monit, daemon

Running Monit 5.4 on an Ubuntu server. When I use `monit reload`, it seems that it restarts monitored services (Tomcat 7 in this situation). Is it the expected behavior? [Documentation says](http://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html) :

> reload - Reinitialize a running Monit daemon, the daemon will reread its configuration, close and reopen log files.

I would expect it not to restart any service but only reload it's configuration, this way I could change email alerts and other stuffs.

This is the output of `monit status`

```
The Monit daemon 5.4 uptime: 15h 0m 

Process 'tomcat7'
  status                            Running
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  pid                               38842
  parent pid                        1
  uptime                            14h 30m 
  children                          0
  memory kilobytes                  3445964
  memory kilobytes total            3445964
  memory percent                    10.4%
  memory percent total              10.4%
  cpu percent                       14.8%
  cpu percent total                 14.8%
  port response time                0.018s to localhost:80 [HTTP via TCP]
  data collected                    Tue, 17 Jun 2014 15:39:36

System 'mytiny.company.net'
  status                            Running
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  load average                      [0.32] [0.49] [0.57]
  cpu                               15.5%us 0.2%sy 0.0%wa
  memory usage                      8217684 kB [25.0%]
  swap usage                        14980 kB [0.7%]
  data collected                    Tue, 17 Jun 2014 15:39:36
```

And this is the Tomcat monitoring configuration in `monitrc`

```
# Tomcat
check process tomcat7 with pidfile /var/run/tomcat7.pid
start program = "/etc/init.d/tomcat7 restart"
stop program = "/etc/init.d/tomcat7 stop"

if cpu > 60% for 2 cycles then alert
if cpu > 80% for 5 cycles then restart

if failed port 80 and protocol http
  then restart
if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

Rest of the file is default, except the check interval that is 60s. Tomcat do runs on 80 port.

Comment: When did you last run `monit reload`? Was it 14.5 hours ago?

Comment: Yes, that's true

Comment: Is there any chance that your CPU % rules are triggering a restart? Remove the CPU rules and try again.

Comment: CPU rules were a problem here.

Comment: Is solution identified ?

Comment: @arvindwill using properly configured services like Systemd / Upstart solved the problem, I mean not the standard `/etc/monitrc` file https://mmonit.com/wiki/MMonit/Setup#autolaunch

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not what's supposed to happen. `monit reload` only rereads its config file and applies new changes. Do you have the same problem if you `service monit restart`?

How do you know Tomcat is actually restarting?

Please paste the output of `monit status`.

Comment: I know it restarts because I see it restarting in the logs ! Updated the question with `monit status` output. Will try what you advice later.

Comment: Also post your monit configuration.